# Переделать рекурсивную функцию в итеративную

Tags: php, рекурсия

Есть рекурсивная функция сложения элементов коллекции, с каждым из которых перед сложением выполняется какая-либо операция (возведение в куб, квадрат и тд). Вот код, он работает:

```
function sum($a, $b, $func) {
    if($a > $b) { 
        return 0;
    }
    return $func($a) + sum($a+1, $b, $func);
}
```

Пытаюсь переделать эту функцию в итеративный тип, не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Вот код

```
function sum($start, $finish, $func){

    $sumIter = function($start, $acc) use ($finish, &$sumIter) {
        if ($start > $finish) {
            return $acc;
        }

        return $sumIter($start + 1, $acc + $func($start));

    };

    return $sumIter ($start,0);
}
```

Ошибка - Undefined variable: func.
Если я подставляю конкретную операцию в этот код, то он работает. Например,

```
function sumSquare($start, $finish){
    $sumIter = function($start, $acc) use ($finish, &$sumIter) {
        if ($start > $finish) {
            return $acc;
        }

        return $sumIter($start+1, $acc+$start*$start*$start);
    };

    return $sumIter($start, 0);
}
```

Comment: $func не существует. создайте её и передайте так же как $finish

Comment: @noadev спасибо!)

Comment: Вы не сделали из рекурсии итерацию. Вы одну рекурсию заменили на другую.

Comment: @ReinRaus возможно я неправильно выразилась. Предполагается, что в новой функции используется итеративный процесс, построенный на рекурсии.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, для вашего случая подойдет более простое решение: [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) + [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php)?

```
<?php
$func = function($in) {
    return ($in * $in * $in);
};
$array = array(1,2,3);
$array = array_map("func", $array);
$summ = array_sum($array);
```

Comment: спасибо! у меня была задача сделать функцию именно с использованием рекурсии и аккумулятора)